# Linux Rasberry Pi - unable to use ssh with mac

Tags: linux, ssh

I just received a rasberry pi and am trying to ssh it with my mac, I have zero linux knowledge.
After I run

```
 ssh 192.168.x.xx -l pi
```

I get

```
 pi@192.168.X.XX's password:
 Permission denied, please try again.
```

Running

```
sudo service ssh status
```

I see a highlighted section

```
pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentification failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=xxx-mbp user=pi

:Failed password for pi from 192.168.x.xx
```

I am entering in the default password 'rasberry'. I can not seem to find a solution, and after spending a few hours messing around am now hoping i have not messed this up even more. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Just to check: are you using the password 'rasberry' as typed in your question, or the default password 'raspberry' ?

Comment: Oh my god :| i feel like an idiot.. and definitely will be needing to get some glasses because i apparently can not read. Thank you !

Comment: To be honest I've done this far more than I'd like to admit ;)

Comment: We all did, at some late hour of the ... morning/afternoon/evening, whatever.

Answer (score 1):

The password is `raspberry` (note the missing `p`).